# How to make a Google Translate API V3 simple HTTP POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-api

I am aware that [documentation exists](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/quickstart)... It's just so damn cryptic and convoluted, typical overengineering. It has to be simpler.

**I don't want to use 3rd party libraries... I want a beautiful vanilla js fetch.**

I am trying the following with `nodejs`...

```js
let url = `https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/PROJECT_ID:translateText?key=API_KEY`;

let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer",         
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: {
        sourceLanguageCode: "en",
        targetLanguageCode: "ru",
        contents: ["Dr. Watson, come here!"],
        mimeType: "text/plain",
    },
});

let result = await response.json();

console.log(result);
```

And getting this error:

```
{ error:
   { code: 401,
     message:
      'Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
     status: 'UNAUTHENTICATED' } 
}
```

Does anyone know the right concoction to pull this off?

Here's a V2 working request:

```js
let url = `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${API_KEY}&format=text&source=de&target=en&q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
```

Comment: You need to remove the Authorization header, if you're not using a bearer

Comment: I am using node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At Google APIs, unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for the POST method. It seems that this is the current specification of Google side. So in your situation, it is required to use the access token.
- Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Authorization: "bearer"`. If the access token is used, please set like `Authorization: "Bearer ###accessToken###"`. `B` of `Bearer` is the uppercase letter. And please insert a space between `Bearer` and `###accessToken###`. Please be careful this.
- Please sent the JSON object as the string value.
- From the official document in your question, the sample curl command is as follows.

  ```
    curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @request.json \
    https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/project-number-or-id:translateText
  ```

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set your access token.

```
let url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/PROJECT_ID:translateText";  // Modified
let response = await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ###accessToken###",  // Modified
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({  // Modified
    sourceLanguageCode: "en",
    targetLanguageCode: "ru",
    contents: ["Dr. Watson, come here!"],
    mimeType: "text/plain",
  }),
});

let result = await response.json();

console.log(result);
```

#### Reference:

- [Translating text (Advanced)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/quickstart)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem even with v2 of that API. Using the header `X-goog-api-key` instead of including the key in the body works so far, however.